# Bootstrap 3 select options cutting off

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to prevent option "cut-offs" on Bootstrap selects?  Please see code below and pictures that follow.  The 1st picture shows the options displaying correctly.  The 2nd picture shows the options cutting off after I resize the screen width to be smaller than the option text.

If I can't do this via CSS, I'm planning on using jQuery to set the width of the select box equal to the largest option width if the option width is bigger than the select width.

```
<select class="form-control multiple" size="3">
    <option>test123 test123 test123 test123 test123 test123</option>
    <option>test123 test123 test123 test123 test123 test123</option>
</select>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you include the relevant code that you're using to resize the select box?

Comment: I'm not resizing the select box...I'm resizing the browser window...

Comment: @ZackMacomber You could try adding "overflow: auto" to your select element. May not deliver your desired end solution but it worked in my test. (Chrome)

Comment: If you re-size the window to smaller than your options list width, what exactly do you expect to have happen?  line break? overflow outside of the browser?   I mean, if there's simply no room, it's going to get cut off and no css or jquery is going to change that. (short of font shrinking to make it fit)

Comment: You could make them word-wrap by adding `word-wrap: break-word;` to one of the select classes. This isn't the perfect solution, but it would increase readability, as there's no scrolling required.
Funny thing: it doesn't seem to with with `word-wrap: normal;`

Comment: @briansol - if I don't use bootstrap's "form-control" on the select, the options all stay visible and don't cut-off.  The native style of a select looks terrible though so that's why I'd like to use bootstrap's "form-control"

Comment: @Freezzo - `word-wrap: normal;` works great in Chrome but not working in IE...half a web developer's life is spent writing browser compatability code...ugh

Comment: @ZackMacomber yeah, you're right. My solution seems only to apply to Chrome. Same with the `overflow: auto`. It's either word-wrapping of overflow on the `<select>` statement.
In FF the best solution seems to be making the options themselves have `overflow:auto`. Although it has bad handling of the scrollbars.
I hope that helps a bit. My IE won't boot (not that I'm complaining :D), so I didn't test it there. I'm afraid there's not much to be done for a pure-css solution other than fixed widths. Good luck with it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that, since Bootstrap containers are responsive by nature, they're automatically going to resize the `<input>` depending on the current size of the browser. Take a look at this structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="I am a very, very, very, very, very, very long option. I'm going to extend off the screen."/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="1">I am a very, very, very, very, very, very long option. I'm going to extend off the screen.</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, if we resize the window smaller and smaller, the width of the `<input>` and `<select>` will adjust to the size of the container it's in `<div class="col-xs-12">`. To prevent this, we would need to use fixed-width inputs, which kinda goes against using a responsive framework like Bootstrap, but I can see the need in some situations.

Some suggestions to consider:

- Is it possible to have smaller option labels?
- Is your `<select>` in a max-width container?
- Could it be possible use a `<modal>` to select your options if there isn't room?

And if all else fails, you can always create a custom class `<div class="col-xs-12 fixed">` and set the width to something static, either a base value or as you suggested using JQuery to find the max-width of the longest option value.

Hope that helps!